# Python script output argument template

Tags: linux, python-2.7

I am writing a basic Python script that ultimately generates a string which is used to call other scripts on the Linux command line.

For example:

```
inputFile = "loadsOfData.csv"
outputFile = "results.txt"
doThis = "-p"
doThat = '-a"


scriptCommand = "./myscript" + " " + inputFile + " " + outputFile + " " + doThis + " " + doThat

os.system(scriptCommand)
```

The order of the command line arguments may change in the future, and I want a check on what is generated.

Is there some way in Python of specifying a template that would make it easy to change the format of the arguments and ensure accuracy?

The real example has a lot more parms than this, so it would be nice for me to be able to specify the order with some template I could edit at the top of the script rather than copy paste everything around in scriptCommand = .... if it does change.

P.S. The actual args come from elsewhere including argv, so are not hard-coded as in my example.

Comment: You should use the [subprocess](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html) module which is meant to replace `os.system`. It accepts a list with the command and its arguments: you can just build that list dynamically and then pass it to the appropriate `subprocess` function.

Answer (score 2):

You should use python [string formatting](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3101/). Define the format you want to use at the top of your file like this:

```
commandFormat = "./myscript {0} {1} {2} {3}"
inputFile = "loadsOfData.csv"
outputFile = "results.txt"
doThis = "-p"
doThat = "-a"
scriptCommand = commandFormat.format(inputFile, outputFile, doThis, doThat)
print scriptCommand

>>> './myscript loadsOfData.csv results.txt -p -a'
```

if you need, say, to have -a appear before -p in all your scriptCommand, change the number order
in the commandFormat variable like this `commandFormat = "./myscript {0} {1} {3} {2}"` and the output will become:

```
>>> './myscript loadsOfData.csv results.txt -a -p'
```